# Boostrap dropdown events not working with bootstrap-ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

According to http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns events (e.g., show.bs.dropdown, hide.bs.dropdown) are thrown when a drowdown is opened/closed. This works until module bootstrap-ui is active. I created a plunkr that shows the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/luYpweQZx22IkWHeMKhM. The events are thrown when the dependency to ui.boostrap is removed, that is

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

is replaced with

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

Versions are: Bootstrap 3.0.3, Angular 1.2.4 (also tested with 1.2.13), Angular UI Bootstrap 0.10.0, JQuery 2.0.3

Seems to be a bug in bootstrap-ui, any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap UI must have over ridden the Bootstrap default js events

I wrote some code to do it .. it might atleast give you some idea

http://plnkr.co/QYKcPEepOrqdyXzfrekH